Type Safe Navigation - Custom List NavType
Hi I'm pretty new to Android and Jetpack Compose so bear with me.
I have a screen with posts and when I click on a post I want to navigate to a separate screen of that post only.
Post data class
@Serializable
data class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val postedDate: String,
    // val likes: List<Like> <--- this doens't work
)

Like data class
@Serializable
data class Like(
    val user: User
)

In my MainActivity:
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = FeedScreen) {
                    composable<FeedScreen> {
                        FeedScreen(navController)
                    }
                    composable<Post> { backStackEntry ->
                        val post: Post = backStackEntry.toRoute()
                        PostScreen(post, onGoBack = { navController.popBackStack() })
                    }
                }
            }

And in my feed screen
...
        Column(
            ...
        ) {
            posts.forEach { p ->
                Post(post = p, onClickCard = {
                    navController.navigate(p)
                })
            }
        }

This seems to work pretty well but if I uncomment the likes attribute, the app fails at runtime with

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot cast likes of type kotlin.collections.List to a NavType. Make sure to provide custom NavType for this argument.

I've been looking around on how to implement a custom NavType for my List but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do this?
Since I'm pretty new I'm not sure if this is the way to do this either so I'd also appreciate if you could give me an alternative. Would it be better to just pass the id and retrieve the Post again from the Db/API?

Having the same problem, did you ever find a solution for this?

follow this article to create a custom nav type
https://medium.com/mercadona-tech/type-safety-in-navigation-compose-23c03e3d74a5
remember to pass the map of nav type to the composable function and the navDeepLink parameter, here is an example
composable<Screen.Note>(
            typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<LinkedHashSet<LabelUi>>() to navTypeOf<LinkedHashSet<LabelUi>>()),
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink<Screen.Note>(
                    basePath = DEFAULT_URI,
                    typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<LinkedHashSet<LabelUi>>() to navTypeOf<LinkedHashSet<LabelUi>>()),
                ),

            )


and here is the navTypeOf implementation:
inline fun <reified T> navTypeOf(
    isNullableAllowed: Boolean = false,
    json: Json = Json,
) = object : NavType<T>(isNullableAllowed = isNullableAllowed) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): T? =
        bundle.getString(key)?.let(json::decodeFromString)

    override fun parseValue(value: String): T = json.decodeFromString(Uri.decode(value))

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: T): String = Uri.encode(json.encodeToString(value))

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: T) =
        bundle.putString(key, json.encodeToString(value))

}

the reason why Uri is used here is mentioned here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBxaZ071N0c
Remember to pass the type map to the toRoute method

Did you encounter the bug UI is flashing so frequently? I want to use an generic builder like yours but it is not okay

No everything works fine in my case, could you provide more information

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/375496207

I don't understand what thing cause my comparision not equals. As what i can see it basically the same. Even, the KSerializer in my snippet return the same reference

I'm not sure but I think you are creating a new instance of CustomType without using remember that's why there is recomposition, maybe you using a data class or a singleton object can solve this issue

Check this out: NavType.SerializableArrayType. You have to add @Serializable onto the T of List<T>.
Also you can check out EnumType, the library has predefined some useful builder for us

I also encountered this problem, I found a solution in the official documentation.Modify your code like this
composable<Post>(
typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<List<Like>>() to LikeNavType)
) { backStackEntry ->val post: Post = backStackEntry.toRoute()
                        PostScreen(post, onGoBack = {navController.popBackStack() })
                    }
                }
val LikeNavType = object : NavType<List<Like>>(isNullableAllowed = false) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): List<Like> {
        return bundle.getSerializable(key) as List<Like>
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): List<Like> {
        return Json.decodeFromString(value)
    }

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: List<Like>): String {
        return Uri.encode(Json.encodeToString(value))
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: List<Like>) {
        bundle.putSerializable(key, value as java.io.Serializable)
    }

}

